# when i create new account successfully, the account's property returns null in the database (JPA)

Tags: java, jpa

I have a Spring Boot project, in which when i create new account successfully, the property of that account returns null in the database

Controller class

```
import javax.validation.Valid;

@Controller
@RequestMapping("/music/backend/user")
public class UserController {
    @Autowired
    UserService userService;
    @GetMapping("list")// Phương thức Get: Lấy dữ liệu ==> load trang ra dự form có sẵn trước
//    @ResponseBody// trả về dạng json
    public String list(Model model,
                       @RequestParam(name = "name",
                               required = false) String name){
        //model: chuyền biến từ java -> jsp
        Object obj= null;
        if(name==null){
            obj=userService.findAll();
        }else{
            obj=userService.searchByEmail(name);
        }
        model.addAttribute("title", name);
        model.addAttribute("list", obj);
        return "/jsp/list.jsp";
    }
    @GetMapping("create")
    public String create(Model model,
                         @RequestParam(name = "name",
                                 required = false) String name){
        //model: chuyền biến từ java -> jsp
//        Object authors= userService.findAllAuthor();
        model.addAttribute("title", "Tạo Mới User");
        UserDto userDto= new UserDto();
        model.addAttribute("userDto",userDto);
//        model.addAttribute("authors", authors);
        return "/jsp/signup.jsp";
    }
//    @GetMapping("edit/{id}")// Phương thức Get: Lấy dữ liệu
//        public String create(Model model, @PathVariable Integer id){
////        Object authors = bookService.findAllAuthor();
//            model.addAttribute("user", userService.getById(id));
//            model.addAttribute("title", "Cập nhật tài khoản");
////        model.addAttribute("authors", authors);
//            return "/jsp/user_edit.jsp";
//    }
    @GetMapping("delete/{id}")
    public String delete(RedirectAttributes redirectAttributes, @PathVariable Integer id){
        userService.deleteById(id);
        redirectAttributes.addFlashAttribute("message", "Xóa thành công");
        return "redirect:/music/backend/user/list";
    }
    @PostMapping(value = "save", consumes = MediaType.APPLICATION_FORM_URLENCODED_VALUE)
    public String save( UserDto userDto,
                       Model model, RedirectAttributes redirectAttributes) {
        userService.save(userDto);
        redirectAttributes.addFlashAttribute("message", "Tạo mới thành công");
        return "redirect:/music/backend/user/list";
    }
}
```

UserDto class

```
@Data
public class UserDto {
    private int id;
    private String username;
    private String email;
    private String password;
    private String sex;
    private Date dob;
}
```

UserEntity class

```
import javax.persistence.*;
import java.sql.Date;
import java.util.Objects;

@Entity
@Table(name = "user", schema = "ktpm", catalog = "")
public class UserEntity {
    private Integer id;
    private String username;
    private String email;
    private String password;
    private String sex;
    private Date dob;

    @Id
    @Column(name = "id")
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    public Integer getId() {
        return id;
    }


    public void setId(Integer id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    @Basic
    @Column(name = "user_name")
    public String getUserName() {
        return username;
    }

    public void setUserName(String username) {
        this.username = username;
    }

    @Basic
    @Column(name = "user_email")
    public String getUserEmail() {
        return email;
    }

    public void setUserEmail(String email) {
        this.email = email;
    }

    @Basic
    @Column(name = "user_password")
    public String getUserPassword() {
        return password;
    }

    public void setUserPassword(String password) {
        this.password = password;
    }

    @Basic
    @Column(name = "user_sex")
    public String getUserSex() {
        return sex;
    }

    public void setUserSex(String sex) {
        this.sex = sex;
    }

    @Basic
    @Column(name = "user_date")
    public Date getUserDate() {
        return dob;
    }

    public void setUserDate(Date dob) {
        this.dob = dob;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object o) {
        if (this == o) return true;
        if (o == null || getClass() != o.getClass()) return false;
        UserEntity that = (UserEntity) o;
        return Objects.equals(id, that.id) &&
                Objects.equals(username, that.username) &&
                Objects.equals(email, that.email) &&
                Objects.equals(password, that.password) &&
                Objects.equals(sex, that.sex) &&
                Objects.equals(dob, that.dob);
    }

    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        return Objects.hash(id, username, email, password, sex, dob);
    }
}
```

UserService class

```
@Service
public class UserService {
    @Autowired
    UserRepository userRepository;
    public String save(UserDto userDto) {
        UserEntity userEntity = new UserEntity();
        BeanUtils.copyProperties(userDto, userEntity);
        // lưu vào db
        userRepository.save(userEntity);
        return "tạo mới thành công ";
    }
    public List<UserEntity> findAll(){
        return userRepository.findAll();
    }
    public  UserEntity getById(Integer id){
        return userRepository.findById(id).get(); // sự # giữa orm và jdbc
    }
    public String deleteById(Integer id){
        userRepository.deleteById(id);
        return "xóa thành công";
    }
    public List<UserEntity> searchByEmail(String email){
        return userRepository.findAllByUserEmailContaining(email);
    }
}
```

user_list.jsp

```
 Danh sách book:
    ${title}
    <br>
    <h2 class="color-red" >${message}</h2>
    <a class="color-red" href="/backend/user/create">Tạo mới</a>
    <br>
    <input id="search" value="${title}"/> <button onclick="searchClick()">Tìm kiếm</button>
    <script>
    function searchClick() {
            var name = document.getElementById("search").value;
            window.location.href = "/backend/user/list?name="+name;
        }
    </script>
    <table>
        <thead>
        <th>Email</th>
        <th>Họ và tên</th>
        <th>Địa chỉ</th>
        <th>Ngày sinh</th>
        <th>Hành động</th>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
        <c:forEach items="${list}" var="s">
            <tr>
                    <td><a href="/backend/user/edit/${s.id}">${s.email}</a></td>
                <td>${s.fullName}</td>
                <td>${s.address}</td>
                <td>${s.dateOfBirth}</td>
                <td><a href="/backend/user/delete/${s.id}">Xóa</a></td>
            </tr>
        </c:forEach>
    
        </tbody>
    </table>
```

when i create new account successfully, the property of that account returns null in the database, how should i fix it

Comment: "create" isn't implemented - it does nothing but return "/jsp/signup.jsp" so it isn't clear what you mean, just as there is nothing called 'account' in the model so we can't be clear what is null in your use case or what you are doing.

Comment: when i go to http://localhost:8686/music/backend/user/create it shows me the registration form
When I click register it registered successfully but in the database the properties I just created return null , I know what I said is quite confusing

Comment: what is your criteria for registered successfully? The backend isn't setup - 'create' doesn't do anything. Compare your create to the save or commented out edit methods. All it is doing is returning a string. I would expect these methods to return the created or updated entity instance

Answer (score 0):

What dependency are you using for BeanUtils ?

org.apache.commons.beanutils
or
org.springframework.beans.

For the first one BeanUtils.copyProperties(Object res, Object src), for the second this is BeanUtils.copyProperties(Object src, Object res).

Comment: i don't think it's related to xml file because i have a similar project, run it successfully and also use same xml file

Comment: I didn't mention the xml file. I wonder if the problem could not come from the object that you save in db. Hence my question about the BeanUtils dependency.

Comment: i using org.apache.commons.bean,utils

Comment: If you use apache try this : "BeanUtils.copyProperties(userEntity, userDto);". You swapped the two elements so you save an empty entity in db.

Comment: If this doesn't work try to use a mapper.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).